# Debugging COM executable

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, com

I'm developing executable COM object with Visual C++ from VS 2010. Now I need to debug it. But where to pass application that uses this COM?
If I put it into `Conf. properties>>Debugging>>Command`, application starts, but not goes through breakpoints in COM code.

UPD:

My project is out-of-process COM server.

I have tested with both `debugging types` - `Native Only` and `Auto` and both debugging modes - `run and + client applications` and `run client application and attach to process from VS COM project`. With none of these cases I was not succeeded with debugging. Debugging breakpoints was not active. I have run from cmd prompt `myCom.exe /RegServr` , but his not helped. How to fix this?

UPD2:

I found that in case I run client application that uses my COM server form another IDE, my current IDE with COM project starts seeing breakpoints and goes through them. How to enplane this behavior? Why breakpoints in COM project are not active while running client app as normal application?

Comment: By "executable COM object", do you mean an out-of-process COM server (a.k.a local server)? Or is it just a DLL (in-proc server)? I have no experience with the former, but with the latter you just debug the application that uses the DLL.

Comment: And if it is an out-of-process server, then start it under the debugger and then run the application separately

Comment: I have updated question body with more information

Comment: @M.M You shoul start the local server debug session by passing "/embedding" as command line. This instructs the server to register itself and waiting for a CreateInstance call.

Comment: /embedding might be used only for COM projects?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have done some or all of the following, but in many cases such problems haunt us because we fail to see the most obvious..

Make sure the executable loads the correct version of your dll implementing your com objects. The "correct" version is the one you have currently built and (or more precisely the version of your dll for which you have pdb files created).

Make sure the debugger type of the project where you have set the debugging command is set to "Native Only" (the default is "Auto").

If you attach to the executable process, make sure the "Attach to" multiple selection list contains at least "Native code".

Comment: I all combination, but this not helped. I have updated question body with comments.

Comment: Is the COM dll build with debug info enabled (C/C++ tab in project properties and "Program Database" defined for entry "Debug Information Format" ? Does the corresponding  pdb file of the COM dll exist in the same folder of the COM dll ?

Comment: While running the executable display the Debug\Windows\Modules window and locate the COM dll row. Is there a Symbol file loaded ? If not, try to locate it yourselve by right clicking on the row and selecting Load Symbols From\Symbol Path.

Comment: In my VS2010 I have only Debug>>Windows>>Breakpoints/Output/Immediate and no Modules there.

Comment: I have only C/C++>>General>>Debug Information Format and it is set to Programm Database for Edit And Continue (/ZI)

Comment: And yes, I have PDB file in Debug folder

Comment: "Debug>>Windows>>Breakpoints/Output/Immediate " are shown when the VS 2010 is not attached to the executable.When you run it the "Modules" appears.

Answer (score 0):

1. start the application that uses the COM object you developed.
2. using VS, debug/attach to the process.
3. set appropriate break point in the COM object source code.

EDIT

if the debugging breakpoints are not active, then it often means that the source may not be the same as the one of the COM object. try doing a clean project and rebuild all. **make sure the right COM server is loaded and registered** i.e. the one in the Debug directory. You can see this by using procexp from sysinternals, it shows the dll loaded for your test app. -- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx

Also another thing that can wrong is that you have not registered the Debug version of the .DLL/.EXE, in that case make sure you register the right one.

Comment: I tried this, but this not helped. I have updated question body with comments.

Comment: I can go through breakpoints when I run client app from IDE. Why? More details in UPD2

Comment: @vico it should work in the same way whether you from VS attach to the client app or run the client app from within VS provided the client exe is bult in debug mode in both cases and the same COM exe is registered and used in both cases.